# Java- How to Display record count

Tags: java

i would like to display the records retrieved after a query in the following format

'Record 1 of 20'

I have the rownum and the total records retrieved. It is just the displaying that i need to know.
It will be great if it could be displayed in a JLabel.

thanks

Comment: Could you please descibe how is your application structured? Are you using the SwingWorker pattern?

Answer (score 0):

```
label.setText("Record "+i+" of "+rownum);
```

Note that you must process events for the value to be displayed, so when you simply set the text and then continue processing (blocking the main thread), the value will be in the widget but the OS won't be able to render it on the screen.

Comment: Please wrap it in SwingUtilities.invokeLater() to be sure.

Comment: If he is doing the query in EDT then yes. If he does it in a separate thread, then the invokeLater() is a safe way to avoid threading problems.

Answer (score 0):

I like using [String.format](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format):

```
label.setText(String.format("Record %d of %d", rownum, total));
```